# Zinc server (scala incremental compiler) on Windows?

Tags: scala

Is there any contribution or hack for getting zinc to work on Windows?  The distro only includes shell scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need a bash environment. For me, I use git bash. Once in terminal, navigate to the bin folder of zinc and type:

```
zinc -start
```

Comment: OK, fortunately I have not been forced to use windoze for dev for a long time.

Comment: In my case, I also needed to put "<path to zinc>\bin\ng\win32" to the path environment variable.

Comment: even when your terminal is navigated to the bin folder of zinc?

Answer (score 1):

Crickets..  Apparently the answer is .. no..  Well that's one more nail in the coffin of doing server side dev on Windows. Zinc just about doubles the compilation speed.

Answer (score 0):

Note: since Dec. 2016, you should be able to use Zinc on any platform supported by the Scala IDE: see "[Scala IDE 4.5.0 is out!](http://scala-ide.org/blog/release-notes-4.5.0-vfinal.html)" (based on the newest Eclipse platform 4.6 Neon).
It does come with:

> ### Zinc compiler
>
> Not only refactorings should work better. We decided to use the newest Zinc compiler to improve performance of compilation.
> For whose of you, who are not familiar with Zinc, it’s worth to say that Zinc is a stand-alone version of sbt’s incremental compiler and can be used as an alternative to scalac.
> Incremental compilation significantly reduces time of compilation because analyzer can find dependent units and limits compilation to them only. So using this powerful tool is the great benefit for Scala IDE.